# Origem histórica de "conto" e "pila" para se referir ao dinheiro

Tags: origem-histórica, regionalismo

Pilim, bago, bufunfa, paus, vintém, verba e dindin provam que existem muitas formas de se referir ao dinheiro, seja euro ou real. Existem dois termos que me intrigam muito.

É muito comum, em situações informais, diálogos como:

> – Quanto *tá* a coca?
>   – Dois *conto*.

No sul brasileiro escuto bastante o termo "pila" para se referir ao dinheiro:

> – E o chocolate?
>   – Quatro *pila*.

"Conto" pra mim é narrativa. Vi que "pila" é de pilantra.

Qual é a origem dos termos "pila" e "conto" no contexto monetário?

Comment: "Conto" vem de "Conto de Réis", uma quantidade da moeda "Réis", usada nos territórios do Império Português (até ser substituída pelo Cruzeiro no Brasil e pelo Escudo em Portugal, que também foram substituídos). Vintém também era um múltiplo de Réis (igual a 20 réis).

Comment: Mas isto ficava melhor em duas perguntas separadas. A parte do conto é fácil; a outra já não sei.

Comment: A outra, "pila", se limita ao Brasil, @Jacinto? Como é em Portugal? Se nunca tiver ouvido eu vou separar as perguntas.

Comment: Aqui no Brasil, "conto" ainda se usa com a moeda atual, mas perdeu o sentido multiplicador (x1000) para a maioria dos falantes. "2 contos" é quase sempre o mesmo que dois reais. O mesmo ocorre com "vintém", que só é usado quando se quer soar mais arcaico. Também usamos "mirréis" (de "mil réis", que também denotava quantidade x1000) e "cruzeiro/cruzado" (moedas que sucederam os Réis) para se referir a valores monetários atuais.

Comment: Em Portugal, que eu saiba, *pila* é apenas uma palavra, suficientemente polida e usada com crianças, para pénis. Mas eu acho que isso é irrelevante para a separação ou não da pergunta em duas. Há imensas perguntas sobre coisas que se aplicam a um país e não a outros. Já há uma [pergunta no meta sobre estes assunto](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-split-some-questions-in-two); a posição a favor de perguntas conjuntas vence nos votos 4-3 a posição contrária, mas eu continuo a achar que as perguntas conjuntas não têm vantagem.

Comment: Origem do Pila ->

A gíria, na verdade, tem raízes na campanha de arrecadação de recursos para sustentar o exílio de Raul Pilla, uma das lideranças políticas gaúchas que apoiaram a Revolução Constitucionalista de 1932.

https://www.terra.com.br/noticias/educacao/correcao-pila-cabuloso-e-truta-veja-origem-de-10-girias-regionais,053842ba7d2da310VgnCLD200000bbcceb0aRCRD.html

Comment: @Jacinto Um conto de réis era um milhão de réis. Mil réis era... milréis mesmo, ou merréis.

Comment: @vnbrs *Pila* até onde eu saiba se limita ao Brasil - e mais precisamente ao sul do Brasil, provavelmente só ao Rio Grande do Sul.

Comment: Eu também tenho a mesma ideia que o Luís. Que mil reis eram um escudo, e um conto de rei mil escudos. A [Wikipedia diz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9is) que `"conto" deriva do latim computus, a conta dez vezes cem mil.`.

Comment: @Luís, é verdade. Já tinha visto isso e comentado na resposta do Peixoto, e esqueci-me deste aqui. No sXIX as pessoas também diziam simplesmente um conto, cinco contos, omitindo o réis. Depois já no meu tempo, um conto passou a ser mil escudos (1 escudo eram mil réis); mas nós dizíamos só um conto, cinco contos, cinco contos e quinhentos (5.500 escudos), já ninguém dizia um conto de escudos. Ainda não ouvi ninguém dizer conto para se referir a mil euros :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conto para dinheiro tem origem nos antigos Réis (conto com o significado de um milhão)

> Sobre o vocábulo conto transcrevo o que ensina o «Grande Dicionário de
>   Dificuldades e Subtilezas do Idioma Português» de Vasco Botelho do
>   Amaral na entrada «Dinheiro»:     «A palavra latina computus deu-nos
>   cômputo (isto é, cálculo, conta) e conto com o significado de um
>   milhão.     «Este significado de milhão na palavra conto pode ver-se
>   num muito célebre passo da Nova Floresta, onde o Padre Manuel
>   Bernardes escreveu:     «O firmamento, pelos cômputos de Ricardo e
>   Clóvis, insignes matemáticos, dista da terra mais de quatrocentos e
>   noventa e um contos, oitocentas e dezoito mil léguas.»     «Hoje
>   diríamos quatrocentos e noventa e um milhões, oitocentas e dezoito mil
>   léguas.     «No entanto, como se sabe, ainda empregamos conto de réis,
>   fazendo-se reviver a esquecida significação de um milhão. Tão
>   esquecido (e é nisto que eu quero principalmente fazer advertir), tão
>   esquecido está o sentido de milhão na palavra conto que a ideia de mil
>   (mil escudos) é a que nos ocorre ao falarmos no conto.     «O povo
>   ainda não sabe filologia, e ainda bem. Não sabe, mas parece que
>   adivinha.     «Calcule-se que, ás vezes, às notas de conto se chama –
>   notas de quilo. Um conto de réis é «um quilo dele». Dele – todos
>   percebem... de quem é; e cá temos outro eufemismo.     «Quilo é mil.
>   Já o era no grego (khíloi, mil).     «É, de facto, curiosa esta
>   coincidência: enquanto no termo conto está desvanecida ou esquecida a
>   noção numérica de milhão, na gíria o quilo vai referindo os mil gramas
>   de dinheiro. Quer o povo dizer, na sua, que as notas de quilo... já
>   pesam coisa que se veja.»

Fonte: [Origem da palavra conto = mil escudos](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/origem-da-palavra-conto--mil-escudos/8460)

Já o Pila (usado sempre no singular), usado no Rio Grande do Sul tem origem no Político Raul Pilla que foi no exílio no Uruguai e na busca de valores para sustentar esse exílio.

> A gíria, na verdade, tem raízes na campanha de arrecadação de
>   recursos para sustentar o exílio de Raul Pilla, uma das lideranças
>   políticas gaúchas que apoiaram a Revolução Constitucionalista de 1932

Fonte: [Pila, cabuloso e truta: veja origem de 10 gírias regionais](https://www.terra.com.br/noticias/educacao/correcao-pila-cabuloso-e-truta-veja-origem-de-10-girias-regionais,053842ba7d2da310VgnCLD200000bbcceb0aRCRD.html)

Comment: A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escudo_portugu%C3%AAs) ajuda a esclarecer. O escudo, criado em Portugal em 1911, valia mil reis, a moeda anterior; então um conto (de reis), que era um milhão de reis, era equivalente a mil escudos; daí que *conto* passasse a designar mil escudos.

Comment: @Jacinto Verdade, "conto" era 1M [réis](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9is), enquanto "mirréis/mil-réis" é que era 1k. Também achava que ambos eram sinônimos. "Mirréis" (ou "mil-réis") sobreviveu por aí também?

Comment: @Seninha, sim, ouvi o pessoal mais velho falar em "mil-réis", "cinco mil-réis", etc. Mas já não me lembro do que significava. Pela lógica, "mil-réis" deveria ser 1 escudo.

Comment: Era escudos, sim. Na aldeia da minha avó os velhotes ainda dizem "marréis" às vezes. (Mas como é pouco prático, dizem-no pouco. Só costumam usá-lo para quantidades pequenas: um pão custa 20 marréis.)

Comment: @ANeves, isto tá-me a vir à memória; na minha zona era mais *merréis*, com os dois ee abertos.

Comment: Dos mais idosos nunca ouvi "mil-réis" como palavras pronunciadas separadamente, apenas "mirreis" ou "merréis" (com o primeiro "e" também aberto). Mas, apesar de estar caindo em desuso, ainda se ouve "réis/merréis", talvez pela semelhança do nome com o plural da moeda atual ("reais"). Mas "conto" é um termo ainda vivo e usado até pelos mais jovens, como gíria.

Comment: @Seninha, eu sempre tive a ideia que *conto* era mil, mas de facto, o pessoal nunca dizia um "conto de escudos"; diziam por vezes era "conto de réis" (para mil escudos, 70 anos depois da substituição dos réis por escudos!), mas o mais comum era simplesmente *conto*.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do Peixoto está correta. Mas como a explicação de "pila" a partir do nome do Raul Pilla soa a etimologia popular, talvez seja bom documentá-la:

[image]

Não achei imagens do reverso (se é que tem um reverso). Não tem a efígie do político (que era o que eu estava esperando), mas tem a assinatura dele, no canto inferior esquerdo, que é o que deve ter originado o termo "pila" como sinônimo de unidade monetária.

A imagem ilustra postagem de outubro de 2014 no [blog do Museu Júlio de Castilhos](http://museujuliodecastilhos.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/) (o Pilla não teria gostado disso...) mas como está hospedada no stack.imgur, e o blog não informa, não sei se o bônus integra o acervo do museu.

Comment: Esse *pila* é masculino? Isto, ["Assim me disse o dr. Pila : — Ovelha velha com fome Não dá mais lã numa esquila. Isso foi posto num jornal Que **precisava de uns pilas**. Borges, Pila e Luzardo São tres nobres gauchos"](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&tbm=bks&q=%22quem+diz+isso+%C3%A9+lobishomem%22&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSwpONk9nWAhXJ1RoKHRtzAYYQvgUIJSgB&biw=1366&bih=662&dpr=1) (1934), deve ser uma das primeiras referências a esses pilas, não?

Comment: Sim, Pila é usado de forma masculina: *Eu não tenho nenhum pila no bolso*.

Comment: @Peixoto - Mais provavelmente, *não tenho um puto pila no bolso*...

Comment: @Peixoto: Dos colegas gaúchos a ouço em ambas as formas, masculina e feminina, mas mais na feminina. Exemplos na forma feminina, bem comum: "Preciso de umas pilas", "Ah ! Bah! Tchê! Isso me custou muitas pilas".

Comment: Bah! Nunca ouvi na forma feminina. Mas vai saber. ;)

Pode até dizer: me dá uns pilas (no plural, nesse caso)

Comment: Morei no Rio Grande do Sul muitos anos. Nunca ouvi ninguém usar "pila" no feminino.

Answer (score 2):

A palavra Pila como moeda, provém do político do Partido Libertador do Rio Grande do Sul , Raul Pilla. Este político e seu partido apoiaram a Revolução Constitucionalista, contra Getúlio Vargas. Como esta revolta foi mais intensa em São Paulo, e teve pouco respaldo no seu estado, ele exilou-se no Uruguai, saído sem levar nenhum dinheiro. Seus partidários, para ajudar no seu sustento, passaram a cotizar-se vendendo bônus com valor de face, que logo passaram a ser negociados, por um breve tempo, como dinheiro entre os seus partidários.

Fontes:

- Irmão Elvo Clemente, pró-reitor da PUC-RS, poeta, escritor, membro da Academia Rio Grandense de Letras – Brasil (in: http://maisativos.com.br/novosite/pila-origem-do-termo/)
- Fonseca, Roberto: História do Rio Grande do Sul para jovens. Porto Alegre, Editora AGE Ltda., 2002 (in: https://books.google.com.br)
- Souza, Blau : Uma no Cravo outra na Ferradura. Porto Alegre, Editora AGE Ltda, 2004 (in: https://books.google.com.br)

Answer (score 0):

1 conto, embora significando 1000 escudos quando existia a moeda escudo, nunca se referiu a 1000 escudos, mas sim a um milhão de réis. Em meados do séc. XX, ainda se dizia habitualmente: 10 000 réis (= 10 escudos); 100 000 réis (100 escudos) ou, por exemplo, 500 000 réis (500 escudos). A uma moeda de 2$50 chamava-se 2 500 réis ou 25 tostões. Um conto de réis era, pois, um milhão de réis. Apesar da mudança da moeda em 1910-11, o povo, calculando as equivalências, continuou a ter como referência os réis: 1 escudo = 1000 réis. 1 tostão = 100 réis = 10 centavos (1/10 de escudo).

Answer (score 0):

Pila vem do revolucionário Raul pila do Uruguai. Criou essa moeda em um revolução.procure que encontras .

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE, Elton! Obrigado pela sua contribuição, mas note que ela não acrescenta em relação às respostas já existentes: nem fontes extras (aliás ela não tem nenhuma fonte, o que é outro problema), nem detalhes adicionais, nem correções, nem qualquer outra informação. Nesse caso, ao invés de postar uma nova resposta, faz mais sentido votar positivamente (clicando na seta para cima ao lado da postagem) nas respostas existentes